# Count in Doctrine/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get a count, using this query:

```
            $count = $entityManager->getRepository('Model:Machine')
                ->createQueryBuilder('m')
                ->select('COUNT(m.id)')
                ->where('m.number = :number')
                ->setParameter('number', $value)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

If I use a `$value` that I know exists, then `$count` returns as `1`.
If I use a value that I know does NOT exist, then `$count` is empty.

Why isn't it set to `0`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getSingleScalarResult works different that you might think.
It expects to get a simple data from query and cast it to an integer.
When query couldn't get machines with number equal to parameter, there are no results, so results variable is empty.